# Is a number divisible by any number in array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to see if a number is divisible by any given numbers in an array.
 I've seen a lot of answers with the number1 % number2 == 0 answer but I haven't found any with an array of numbers and I'd rather not write out each number in the array myself (that would be working too hard).

So here is what I'm trying to figure out. As you can see the only way this works currently is if the  last number I give it is true otherwise the else statement kicks in and evaluates number1_result to false.

```
int square_numbers[10] = { 4, 9, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144 };
int number1;    
bool number1_result;

cin >> number1; 

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if(number1 % square_numbers[i] == 0)
        number1_result = true; 
    else
        number1_result = false;
}
```

How do I make sure that if the loop ever evaluates to true once, it is true. If its not true at least one time, it is false.

Let me know if you need more info and thank you!

Comment: `number1_result == true/false` is a condition, change `==` to `=`

Comment: Break the loop as soon as you find a divisor.  There is no need to keep checking the others.

Comment: [Turn on warnings.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9cadc9857b846e5)

Comment: Not really related to your question but you can skip 4, 9 and 25 because they have multiples included in the array. More generally, if you want to test many numbers against the same array, it could meke sense to check for such cases first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break the loop once you find a divisor.And use `=` instead of `==` for assignment.    
Correct solution is-

```
int square_numbers[10] = { 4, 9, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144 };
bool number1_result=false;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if(number1 % square_numbers[i] == 0) {
        number1_result = true;
        break;
    } 
}
```

Problem with your code is that it overwrites number_result even if it is already true.

Consider the example, `number1=4`, `square_number={2, 3}`
In your loop `num_result` will become `true` at first comparison but it will again become `false` on next comparison with `3`.

Comment: Only after the time limit

Answer (score 2):

With `std`:

```
bool number1_result = std::any_of(std::begin(square_numbers),
                                  std::end(square_numbers),
                                  [&](auto e){ return number % e == 0; });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are assigning `number1_result` which should check inside the loop but instead you have to input `number1`:

```
cin >> number1_result; // redundant
```

The answer:

```
int square_numbers[10] = { 4, 9, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144 };
bool number1_result = false;

int number1;
cin >> number1;  

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if(number1 % square_numbers[i] == 0){
        number1_result = true;
        break;
    }
}
```